# POWER function result SQL different with Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008-r2

Can someone help me with POWER function in T-SQL..?

I am trying to calculate this in my stored procedure, this formula is coming from an Excel file

```
=(1 - 3.3387306 * LN(0.234367344) + 1.426559 * (LN(0.234367344)) ^ 2)
```

I write it down in my stored procedure like this:

```
=(POWER(1 - 3.3387306 * LOG(0.234367344) + 1.426559 * (LOG(0.234367344)), 2))
```

- The result in Excel is: `8.846971361`
- The result in T-SQL is: `14.2453699180547`

Why are the results different? Am I writing it wrong in T-SQL? Please help.

Cheers,

Comment: Just the value of LN(0.234367344) and LOG(0.234367344).

Comment: Yes, you're right. So what function should i use in sql for LN function? It should be LOG. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LOG` is giving you the natural log. You have a problem with your parentheses

```
1 - 3.3387306 * LOG(0.234367344) + 1.426559 * POWER(LOG(0.234367344)), 2)
```

should give you the same answer as Excel.

Comment: Cheers mate, need more concentrate and focus. :)